# RTP Reverse Proxy

Tags: vlc, streaming, reverse-proxy, cvlc

I've been trying to make a prototype of a video streaming server before I actually write code for it. So I used VLC to make streaming happen on my server using the following command:

```
cvlc video.mpg --loop --sout '#transcode{vb=0,vcodec=mpgv,fps=20,ab=0,acodec=mpga,channels=2,venc=ffmpeg}:rtp{mux=ts,ttl=10,dst=127.0.0.1,port=9554}'
```

The streaming service began running on **localhost** on port 9554. After a little research, I failed to bind VLC stream to a public IP, that's another problem worth sharing on another page.
The thing is, to make streaming visible from the outside world I used NginX reverse proxy, and used **HTTP** streaming on VLC over **RTP**.

```
cvlc video.mpg --loop --sout '#transcode{vb=0,vcodec=mpgv,fps=20,ab=0,acodec=mpga,channels=2,venc=ffmpeg}:http{mux=ts,ttl=10,dst=0.0.0.0:9554/live}'
```

Well, That was a success to watch the streamed video on my phone except that I was not using **RTP** protocol.
The problem raises when I have no idea how to reverse proxy a **UDP Stream**. Sure NginX will not work because it only proxies HTTP, and TCP on newer versions, of course.
So, any idea how to reverse proxy a **UDP stream**?
Any other relative answers are also welcome, in case you have any idea how to bind VLC to a public address instead of localhost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RTP is used in conjunction with the RTP Control Protocol (RTCP).

While RTP carries the media streams (e.g., audio and video), RTCP is used to monitor transmission statistics and quality of service (QoS) and aids synchronization of multiple streams.

Typically RTP will be sent on an even-numbered UDP port, with RTCP messages being sent over the next higher odd-numbered port.

I think that's why you have failed to bind RTP on to a public ip address you forgot about RTCP.

And again i think what you need is a DNAT not a reverse proxy.

My advice is to use HLS rather than RTP if you want to stream video and audio on internet it's more flexible than RTP and other similar protocols, and you can use Nginx to serve HLS.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_hls_module.html

Comment: Great points, thanks. Haven't heard of HLS before though it seems pretty popular. I'll dig more for it.

Answer (score 0):

RTP normally can work over TCP too. Normally, adding `?transport=tcp` at the end of link works, but I am not sure about your case.